# How to show the state equation that $x_1=x_2$ can only happen at the origin

Tags: nonlinear-system, stability-theory, nonlinear-dynamics, lyapunov-functions

Take a look at this system:
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1 &= x_2 \\
\dot{x}_2 &= -\frac{x^2_1}{x_2} - x_2 + x_1
\end{align}
$$
Take a Lyapunov function as 
$$
V(x_1,x_2) = x^2_1 + x^2_2
$$
Its time derivative is 
$$
\dot{V}(x_1,x_2) = -2(x_1 - x_2)^2 \leq 0 
$$
The authors state the following:

> Since $\dot{V}(x) = 0 $ for all $x_1 = x_2$,  we need to check whether
>   the origin is the only point where $\dot{V}(x) = 0 $. It can be seen
>   from the state equation that $x_1 = x_2$ can only happen at the origin,
>   therefore the origin globally asymptotically stable.

It is not clear to me how *from the state equation that $x_1 = x_2$ can only happen at the origin*. Any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

Making

$$
\cases{
x_1\dot x_1 = x_1 x_2\\
x_2\dot x_2 = -x_1^2-x_2^2+x_1x_2
}
$$

after subtracting  we have

$$
\frac 12(x_2^2-x_1^2)' = \frac 12((x_2+x_1)(x_2-x_1))'=-(x_1^2+x_2^2) < 0,\ \ \forall (x_1,x_2) \ne (0,0)
$$

Comment: "after subtracting" could you please illustrate this? Also, how did you come up with this term $\frac{1}{2}(x^2_2-x^2_1)'$.

Comment: @CroCo $a - b$ is a subtraction and $\frac 12(x_2^2-x_1^2)' = x_2\dot x_2-x_1\dot x_1$

Answer (score 1):

I think that what the author states is badly worded. Namely I am assuming that the author is referring to [LaSalle's invariance principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaSalle%27s_invariance_principle), which roughly states that when $\dot{V}(x)=0$ it won't remain zero unless $x=0$ this shows asymptotic stability. This can be done in your case by checking the dynamics at $x_1=x_2$ which allows us to simplify $\dot{x}_2$ to

$$
\dot{x}_2 = -x_1.
$$

Combining this with $\dot{x}_1 = x_2$ allows us to show that the system won't remain on the manifold $x_1=x_2$ unless $x_1=x_2=0$. This won't mean that the system will never have that $x_1=x_2\neq0$, but it does show that the system won't remain at that manifold.

Comment: What do you mean by the term manifold?!

Comment: @CroCo A lower dimensional subspace, in this case $\{x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}\,|\,x_1=x_2\}$.

Comment: Thanks.........